# Как выбрать записи по дате на день, если они могут растягиваться на несколько дней?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть инструмент, который выбирает записи за промежуток 1 день. Но некоторые записи могут длиться несколько дней, начинаться или заканчиваться в предыдущий или следующий день, т.е.:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| start       | end         |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 03.30 9:00  | 03.31 6:25  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 03.31 18:20 | 04.02 13:00 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 04.01 15:20 | 04.05 9:00  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 04.01 14:40 | 04.01 17:30 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 04.02 11:50 | 04.04 12:15 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

И я что-то не догоняю, как правильно составить запрос для этой ситуации, когда нужно получить данные в период дня 04.01:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| start       | end         |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 03.31 18:20 | 04.02 13:00 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 04.01 15:20 | 04.05 9:00  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 04.01 14:40 | 04.01 17:30 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой фильтр должен помочь

```sql
WHERE start < '2020-04-02 00:00:00' 
 AND  end >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87d4b1/4 походу похоже на то